# ASP.NET CSV File Download

Tags: asp.net, csv

I have a website that was written for me in 2007 by a very reputable IT firm. They have upgraded and maintained it wonderfully all these years...up until a few month's ago. Their response times have gone from 1-2 days to 3-5 weeks.

Anyway, I'm not an ASP programmer but I have made many small changes myself over the years such as field additions,, etc. My website provides the ability to print a report or download a CSV file from several search results pages. I have Crystal Reports so I can modify the reports, but I also need to add a couple of fields to the CSV download. But, I can't find where this info is stored in any of the ascx/aspx files.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting the csv data from? From a database? Or are you exporting the report data to a csv format?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has spent the last three years building and maintaining a .NET web application with these functions I can say with certainty there is more than one way to skin a cat!

As a starting point and based on certain assumptions, try searching through the code base for any references to ".csv" or ".rpt" file extensions. Once found, this should give you some context as to how the application is handling these items.

Worth noting, CrystalDecisions (the library for handling Crystal reports) is limited to specific versions of .NET and you may find there is a piece of middleware handling Crystal - this is what we ended up doing.

Comment: Well, I suspect that's why I can't find any reference to CSV files in the files I have.  I guess I don't have the code base...just editable ascx & aspx files.

Comment: You need the source code, that code will be vb.net, or c#, but each aspx page has a correnponding code page and code class. Without that source code, you really can't change code logic here at all. The aspx pages are only a small part of the system, and usually only much the display or UI part, but the real meat and potato's and operation of the application is of course going to be the actual code that does the useful part and work of any good application.